# Rails engine, invoking container app's native migration generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, generator

Others on SO have asked (and been answered) about how to write a migration template which will be copied to the container app just like any other template. We're writing a Rails engine which needs to work in multiple major versions of Rails, so we're hoping to find a way to use the app's native migration generator to generate migrations, rather than either having to maintain multiple templates, or needing to write a complex template which can handle multiple major versions.

I have seen in [the Rails engine documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#generate) (9.12) that you can invoke other generators like so:

```
generate "scaffold", "forums title:string description:text"
```

where the name of the generator, and its arguments, are single strings. However, the following doesn't work for us:

```
generate 'migration', 'create_table_name column1:type ...'
```

For us, regardless of Rails version, a migration file is created with the proper name, but empty `up` and `down` (or `change`) methods. So it's as if only the first argument is actually being received by the native migration generator.

Is there in fact a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked fine for me by using the camel case generate syntax:

`lib/generators/test_generator.rb`

```
class TestGenerator < Rails::Generators::Base                                  
  def build_table                                                              
    generate 'migration', 'CreateFoo name:string'                              
  end                                                                          
end
```

`rails g test` created the migration:

`db/migrate/20170128040004_create_foo.rb`

```
class CreateFoo < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]                                    
  def change                                                                      
    create_table :foos do |t|                                                     
      t.string :name                                                              
    end                                                                           
  end                                                                             
end
```

So I think you just need to use the syntax `CreateTableName` and not `create_table_name`.